# problem with integration of bootstrap in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have started a new project in MVC 5 and i have downloaded a bootstrap template. the template works okay as a normal website.. But when I try to integrate it on the .net project it doesn't works. I have attached picture for better understatement.
[Normal HTML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daFDz.jpg).
[MVC Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knpgl.png)

Here is my MVC code in _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../Content/img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <title>Fashiop</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/bootstrap.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/linericon/style.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/css/font-awesome.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/lightbox/simpleLightbox.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/nice-select/css/nice-select.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/animate-css/animate.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css")">
    <!-- main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/css/style.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/css/responsive.css")">
</head>

<body>

    <!--================Header Menu Area =================-->
    <header class="header_area">
        <div class="top_menu row m0">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>Call Us: 012 44 5698 7456 896</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <ul class="right_side">
                        <li>
                            <a href="login.html">
                                Login/Register
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                My Account
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">
                                Contact Us
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main_menu">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand logo_h" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <div class="row w-100">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 pr-0">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav center_nav pull-right">
                                    <li class="nav-item active">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Shop</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="category.html">Shop Category</a>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="single-product.html">Product Details</a>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="checkout.html">Product Checkout</a>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="cart.html">Shopping Cart</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="confirmation.html">Confirmation</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Blog</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="single-blog.html">Blog Details</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="tracking.html">Tracking</a>
                                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                <a class="nav-link" href="elements.html">Elements</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right right_nav pull-right">
                                    <hr>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="icons">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                    <hr>

                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="icons">
                                            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                    <hr>

                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="icons">
                                            <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                    <hr>

                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="#" class="icons">
                                            <i class="lnr lnr lnr-cart"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                    <hr>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--================Header Menu Area =================-->
    @*<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>*@
    @*<div class="container body-content">*@
    @RenderBody()

    @*<footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>*@


    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/popper.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/stellar.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/lightbox/simpleLightbox.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/nice-select/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/isotope/isotope-min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/flipclock/timer.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Content/vendors/counter-up/jquery.counterup.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/mail-script.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/theme.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can press F12 in your browser, to see what errors you are getting.

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody here can debug for you. Use the tools you have access to - like browser dev tools to see what errors are being raised. Are the images that the theme expects available? In the right path? Does the theme expect resources to be in some specific folder? Nobody here can answer that for you. These things don't really have anything to do with `MVC`(or any other platform for that matter)